# Incorrectly calculated sum expressionForKeyPath sum: core data

Tags: objective-c, math, core-data, expression

May be I'm doing something wrong?

So, I have few Entities with relationship
"Shop->amountIncome and -> amountExpense"

And I'm trying to count total income and expense.
I have dynamic tabelView

I start with

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

and some search

```
Shop *shop = nil;
if (self.searchPredicate == nil) {
    shop = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
else {
    shop = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:self.
            searchPredicate][indexPath.row];
}

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = shop.shopName;
```

So I start with request of my entity "Shop" (it has relationship -> amountIncome and 
->amountExpense

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Shop"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

I have several Shops, so I do predicate by shopName

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"shopName = %@", shop.shopName]];
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
```

after all I do stuff for calculating sum:

```
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
expressionDescription.name = @"amountIncome";
expressionDescription.expression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"@sum.incomes.amountIncome"];
expressionDescription.expressionResultType = NSDecimalAttributeType;

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescriptionExpense = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
expressionDescriptionExpense.name = @"amountExpense";
expressionDescriptionExpense.expression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"@sum.expenses.amountExpense"];
expressionDescriptionExpense.expressionResultType = NSDecimalAttributeType;

fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[expressionDescription, expressionDescriptionExpense];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",result);

if (result == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
else
{
    NSNumber *sumOfAmounts = [[result objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"amountIncome"];
    NSNumber *sumOfAmountsExpense = [[result objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"amountExpense"];

    NSString* amount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"inc %@/ exp %@/ difference",
                        sumOfAmounts, sumOfAmountsExpense];
```

and results I'd like to show in detailTextLabel

```
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = amount;
}
return cell;
```

The thing is, that amountIncome counting correct, but amountExpense counting wrong (like double counting)
What I'm missing, what my mistake?
P.S. Sorry my English ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried KVC?

```
NSNumber *sumIncome = [allIncomes valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amountIncome"];
NSNumber *sumExpense = [allExpenses valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amountExpense"];
```

Comment: Thank you and BIG respect for your answer @Mundi !!!! Am I need to use NSExpressionDescription ?

Comment: No, that's the great thing about KVC. Also, you might consider expressing your respect by clicking the up-vote button as is customary on this platform.

Comment: And one more thing looking into my question. It looks like problem in 'propertiesToFetch' if I fetching either 'expressionDescriptionIncome' or 'expressionDescriptionExpense' only, everything counting correctly. But this 'fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[expressionDescriptionIncome, expressionDescriptionExpense];' looks fine and I don't understand why that messaround. Should I need make two different fetchRequest? Or problem in "NSArray *result", may be I should make NSArray for amountIncome and amountExpense separate?

Comment: Yes, with NSExpression you would need two fetch requests. For the KVC solution, don't specify `propertiesToFetch` and just fetch normal managed objects. Then use the two lines above.

Comment: Thanks, Mundi! I need time to discover it, so I will try your method and let you know

Comment: Thanks, @Mundi ! That's work fine) I did it without FetchRequest just '  Shop *shop = nil; NSNumber *sumIncome = [shop.incomes valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amountIncome"];
        NSNumber *sumExpense = [shop.expenses valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amountExpense"];' Is it correct way? And how about minus operation ( x - y = z)?????